# Why does $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor n \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x} \rfloor = n-1$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am given the following solution but I don't understand why does the greatest integer value of a natural number multiplied to a value which is less than $1$ is coming out to be $n-1$. Can you explain why?

> Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \lfloor n \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor + \lfloor n \cdot \frac{\tan x}{x} \rfloor \right)$

Solution:

> Since $\sin x < x$ and $\tan x > x$, the quantity of interest is equal to $(n-1) + n = 2n-1$.

Comment: welcome to MSE, please learn to type [math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) on this site, avoid using picture whenever possible for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we also have $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x}=1$. They are arbitrarily close to $1$ at the neighborhood of $x=0$. Also, around that neighborhood besides $x=0$, we have $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ being strictly less than $1$ but it can be made arbitarily close to $1$ and $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ being strict greater than $1$ but it can get arbitrarily close to $1$.

Hence $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor n \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\rfloor = n-1$ since I can make $x$ close enough that $n-1 < n \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}< n$. I just have to consider a neighborhood near $0$, $x \ne 0$, $1-\frac1n < \frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$.

and $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor n \cdot \frac{\tan x}{x}\rfloor = n$ since I can make $x$ close enough that $n < n \cdot \frac{\tan x}{x} < n+1$. I just have to consider a neighborhood near $0$, $x \ne 0$, $1 < \frac{\tan x}{x} < 1+\frac1n$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ne 0$, $$\frac{\sin x}x<1\text{ and }\frac{\tan x}x>1$$  so that $$\left\lfloor n\frac{\sin x}x\right\rfloor<n\text{ and }\left\lfloor n\frac{\tan x}x\right\rfloor\ge n.$$

On another hand, for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$,

$$\left\lfloor n\frac{\sin x}x\right\rfloor\ge n-1\text{ and }\left\lfloor n\frac{\tan x}x\right\rfloor<n+1.$$

---

In other words, for tiny $\epsilon$ (smaller than $\frac1n$ but positive),

$$\lfloor n(1-\epsilon)\rfloor=n-1\text{ and }\lfloor n(1+\epsilon)\rfloor=n.$$